# .filter does not return object in correct order

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects(suggestions) with ids and an array containing only ids(attributes). I need to make a new array with the objects from suggestions that have a similar id found in attributes.

```
suggestions: 

Name:"NAME_1"
Value:"16"
id:"295748b6-bf55-4225-add8-aaf000e4825a"


Name:"NAME_2"
Value:"something"
id:"68a65c6d-5a09-4e8a-8583-aaf000e4825a"

Name:"NAME_3"
Value:"4"
id:"69984329-eed1-47a2-8806-aaf000e4825a"

...
```

attributes:

```
attributes:Array[3]
0:"69984329-eed1-47a2-8806-aaf000e4825a"
1:"295748b6-bf55-4225-add8-aaf000e4825a"
2:"68a65c6d-5a09-4e8a-8583-aaf000e4825a"
```

function:

```
const chosenAttributes = this.suggestions.filter(
    item => this.attributes.includes(item.id)
    );
    this.chosenAttributes = chosenAttributes;
```

Output:

```
chosenAttributes:Array[3]
0:Object
Name:"NAME_1"
Value:"16"
id:"295748b6-bf55-4225-add8-aaf000e4825a"
1:Object
Name:"NAME_2"
Value:"something"
id:"68a65c6d-5a09-4e8a-8583-aaf000e4825a"
2:Object
Name:"NAME_3"
Value:"4"
id:"69984329-eed1-47a2-8806-aaf000e4825a"
```

This works however I need to have the objects in my new array(chosenAttributes) be in the same order that their ids appear in my attributes array. I'm not sure why they're not ordered correctly from the start.

Vue 2.6.11

Comment: tag should be `javascript` as it has nothing to do with `vueJs`, and please add some example data that you have in your `suggestions` variable, as well what are you expecting to output so it's easier for anyone to help

Comment: Please give us working examples of suggestions and attributes. The example you have is not valid code and we need to know the exact structure of both objects to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.filter` does not change the order of the initial array, which is `suggestions` in your case. If you want a different order (order of the `attributes` array) you have to sort the new array in an extra  step.

```
chosenAttributes.sort ( function (a, b)
{
    return this.attributes.indexOf (a.id) - this.attributes.indexOf (b.id);
});
```

Comment: Had to change it a little bit for Vuejs but it works: this.chosenAttributes.sort((a, b) => {
        return (
          this.attributes.indexOf(a.id) -
          this.attributes.indexOf(b.id)
        );
      });

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to use Javascript's Array `sort` method:

```
const chosenAttributes = this.suggestions
  .filter(
    item => this.attributes.includes(item.id)
  )
  .sort(item => /* return 1, 0, or -1 to indicate sorting */);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort has further details.